# Reading from an oscilloscope to MATLAB and the integer/byte value limit

Tags: matlab

I'm having an issue with data acquisition from an oscilloscope. MATLAB captures values that are over the limit of 255 for BYTE format and 65,535 for an unsigned 16-bit integer when using the WORD format, and loops these values back from 0 resulting in a very distorted waveform. I'm using the following code and reading the data using binblockread:

```
clear all

clc

close all

%%

DSO_S_104A=instrfind('Type', 'visa-usb', 'RsrcName', 'USB0::0x2A8D::0x904A::MY54340109::0::INSTR', 'Tag', '');

DSO_S_104A.InputBufferSize = 350000;

DSO_S_104A.ByteOrder = 'littleEndian';

fopen(DSO_S_104A);

%% SETUP

set(DSO_S_104A, 'Timeout', 0.5);

%Set number of points

fprintf(DSO_S_104A, ':ACQUIRE:POINTS 48000');

% Set sample rate

fprintf(DSO_S_104A, ':ACQUIRE:SRATE 0.5e9');

% Turn interpolation off for faster averaging

fprintf(DSO_S_104A, ':ACQUIRE:INTERPOLATE OFF');

fprintf(DSO_S_104A,'*TRG');

fwrite(DSO_S_104A,'SYSTem:HEADer OFF');

% Specify data from Channel 1

fprintf(DSO_S_104A,':WAVEFORM:SOURCE CHAN1'); 

fprintf(DSO_S_104A,':WAVEFORM:FORMAT BYTE');

fprintf(DSO_S_104A,':WAVEFORM:BYTEORDER LSBFirst');

fprintf(DSO_S_104A, 'WAVEFORM:STREAMING OFF');

%%

fwrite(DSO_S_104A,sprintf(':WAV:DATA?\n'));

data2 = binblockread(DSO_S_104A);

plot(data2)

end
```

The waveform I would like to sample is the middle one (yellow) on this image: [image]
and the result looks like this: [image]

The data is obviously there, but the sampled values higher than 255 loop back and distort everything.
Is there any way to fix this? I know that for the case of 2pi jumps in phase measurements the "unwrap" command can help, but is there anything for amplitude?

Also, If anybody has any advice how to speed up the data acquisition  process from a scope to MATLAB I would welcome any suggestions.  Currently to capture one "screen" from the scope it takes MATLAB about  0.04 seconds which remains the same for up to 3-4x the number of points. 
I can raise the number of points which puts multiple "scope screens" in one acquisition thus speeding up the proccess (by later cutting each  "screen" into a different vector), but it also makes the data processing a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the expected format explicitly. Such as `data_read = binblockread(DSO_S_104A,'int16');`

Otherwise, Matlab may interpret and cast the byte stream in strange ways.

Another solution would be to manually cast the data read from the instrument:

```
// read and cast to uint8, as Matlab tends to cast everything to double
data2 = uint8(binblockread(DSO_S_104A));

// now you have an uint8 array with values in the 0-255 range
// typecast (i.e. re-interpret the binary representation of your numbers as another data type, here 'int16')
data_test = typecast(data2(:),'int16'); // or 'int32', or 'float', or 'int8', or...

// try to swap bytes, in case the data from the instrument does not have the same endianness as the computer
data_test_reverse_endianness = swapbytes(data_test);

// plot and see if it makes sense
plot([data_test,data_test_reverse_endianness]);
```

Try with several formats, with or without the `swapbytes` and see which one works.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ever encounters a similar issue here is how I solved it:
In the end the issue was offset voltage on the scope coupled with v/div setings. For some reason zeroed offset was a major problem. I raised the offset voltage (which basically raises the waveform on the scope) until I started capturing the correct waveform, as well as played a bit with the volt/div settings (to a lesser extent).  Weird issue.